# How to add post title in link

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using adcenter ads, which are as follows-

> ads.ad-center.com/offer?prod=101&ref=5030200&q=**Keyword**

Now i want to replace Keyword in link with post title automatically. i have tried this code, but it return first word from title, code is-

```
<?php
 $title = get_the_title();
 echo "<a href=http://ads.ad-center-com/offer?prod=101&ref=5030200&q=$title >Download</a>"
?>
```

please solve it or tell me other method to add title in link automatically.
Thanks

Comment: your title must contain some space, so customize your title add '-' or '_'

Answer (score 1):

In your case the value of the `href` attribute in your `a` tag must be encapsulated into double quotes, as it can contain spaces. You can escape them like this:

`echo "<a href=\"http://ads.ad-center-com/offer?prod=101&ref=5030200&q=$title\">Download</a>";`

or you can use the concatenation:

`echo '<a href="http://ads.ad-center-com/offer?prod=101&ref=5030200&q=' . $title . '">Download</a>';`

Comment: It can also be done by single quote. but nice catch :)

Comment: This is wrong. Attribute quotes are **optional** in HTML5.

Comment: But not with the case of URL query string containing spaces! 
What W3C validation says about it.
"in an unquoted attribute value. Probable causes: Attributes running together or a URL query string in an unquoted attribute value" So it must be quoted or URL must be encoded. @mevius

Comment: That's true @Sumit, which is why I upvoted your answer. But Jeremy's answer incorrectly states that `href`s must be encapsulated in quotes. This is wrong, but wouldn't be if he added info about spaces in URLs.

Comment: I just wanted to say that it must be encapsulated in quotes in this case. I see now that my answer was in fact unclear (I edit them right now).

Answer (score 1):

When you are adding some string in URL remember to [encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the string.

```
$title = urlencode(get_the_title());
echo "<a href='http://ads.ad-center-com/offer?prod=101&ref=5030200&q=$title'>Download</a>";
```